# List Field in Model-- Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am newbie in django,working on rest API framework. I want to ask the user for certain details to be put in html format, like popularity, name of some book.

A book can belong to various category such as Friction, Romantic, Action.
So I want to have a list Field for category. 
Two options can be given, one ask the user to enter the category and append in the list at the backend. Or provide a list from which user can choose.

Have tried the below code in model.py

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.category


 class Books(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     date = models.DateTimeField()
     category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
     #category = models.ForeignKeyField(Category) #tried Foreign key Model Field also


     def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Please help me out. Is that the correct approach or should try something else.
Thanks in advance.

Its working fine, But instead of showing the values on the admin panel, it shows Category Object in the Books Model Table.

```
[
  {
    "name": "Harry Potter",
    "date": 03-03-2014,
    "category": 6
  }
]
```

Where at category 6 there is String value as "Magical"

am I missing anything

Comment: Yes you are going in the right direction. The model declaration seems fine as per your needs. I would advice you to use 'related_name' as well.

category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='some_rel_name')

Comment: Thanx Ankur, I am using ForeignKey Field, But its giving the error as book_api.category_id may not be null.  Any Idea about this.

Comment: Many to Many fields seemed perfect for your case. Why go for Foreign Key.
Anyway with Foreign Key as declared, you must be trying to insert or update Books record but not providing a proper value for category foreign key. Is it the case ?

Comment: No, Its says that category_id column doesn't exists. And as per my understanding,the category_id column is auto-generated. We don't define it for every class model. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I think this approach is correct with a ManyToManyField, because a book could have so many categories and a category could have so many books.

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.category


 class Books(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     date = models.DateTimeField()
     category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)


     def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Each book belongs to only one category (or genre), so what you need is a foreign key (not many to many relationship). Your `Book` model should look like below:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publication_date = models.DateTimeField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**Notes:**

- It's better to use `publication_date` or `published` instead of `date` to not shadow `date` in case you imported it from `datetime` module for example.
- A book is characterized by its title (so it's better to call the first field title instead of name)
- `on_delete=models.CASCADE` means if a category is deleted, all its related books will be deleted too.

Comment: Hi ettanany, Have tried Foreign Key earlier but its not working that's why switched from Foreign Key to ManyToMany Field. Error which is showing is project_name.category_id may not be NULL

Comment: What's `project_name`? a `Category` instance?

Comment: No, doesn't seem so.  project_name is the app name. And Category is the clss I have created in model.py same as the mention Code.

Comment: And as per my understanding, category_id is auto-generated? Right?

Comment: Even I have migrate the models again, After that its saying OperationalError: no such column: project_name.category_id.. Not understanding whats happening here.

Comment: Can you remove all your migrations (folders) and run `python manage.py makemigrations` again?

Comment: python manage.py makemigrations <app_name> is running fine. But after that python manage.py migrate is giving InconsistentMigrationHistory Error.. :(

Comment: You need to remove your previous migrations first

Comment: Hey..Have deleted the db.sqlite3 file also..It worked. But when creating the list in the admin Panel, Its showing Category Object, not the name of category.

Comment: Make sure you have `def __str__(self):` in your `Category` model

Comment: Thanks, It worked. And just realized that its better to use ManyToMany Field as category, as a book can belong to many category. Right